# Stripe payment popup in mobile device

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'am using `Stripe` payment in my website.

**Process**

When clicking on the `checkout button` i'am sending a `Ajax` request (at the server end i'am doing some DB transaction which should be run before the payment happens) and then show the popup on ajax success. Its working perfectly on chrome and other desktop browsers.

**But** Its not working on `mobile browsers` (popup block issue happens).

I know i can solve this by opening the popup just after the click without waiting to ajax success as in this [Stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-more-runloop)

But in my case i need to wait until i get the response from the server

How do i fix this Or is there anything that I can handle my case? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to rework your site so that you do the ajax request before the user clicks checkout. Maybe one button that does the ajax and then when the response comes back then you enable another button that opens checkout

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this happens because you are not opening Stripe Checkout directly in the click handler. You need to call `handler.open()` when the customer clicks on an element on the page and not in a callback. This indicates to the browser that the user has explicitly requested the popup. Otherwise, mobile devices and some versions of Internet Explorer will block the popup and prevent users from checking out.